# sql skip result based on value

Tags: sql, filtering

Lets say I have a bunch of images/post, where I join images metadata.
If `_wp_attachment_image_alt` does not have a value, then it should skip the result. Please note that it should skip the entire result of that post/image, and not just the row.

What I have tried is this:

```
SELECT 
                id, 
                post_title,
                guid,meta_key
            FROM 
                posts a 
            LEFT JOIN 
                postmeta b ON a.id = b.post_id
            WHERE
                post_type = 'attachment'
            AND
                meta_key NOT LIKE '_wp_attachment_image_alt'
            limit 20
```

This kinda works but not what I would like it to. It should skip the post from `wcuq_post`, and not just one row of `wcuq_postmeta`.

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  post_title,
  guid,
  meta_key
FROM 
  posts a 
LEFT JOIN 
  postmeta b ON a.id = b.post_id
WHERE
  post_type = 'attachment'
  AND id IN (SELECT post_id FROM postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attachment_image_alt' AND meta_value != '')
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: you should explain your answer an not just put it here

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality
Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some
guidelines for [How do I write a good
answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are
**not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted
because they are less useful to a community of learners. Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.